Render with RgbdSensor on server
How can I use RgbdSensor for rendering on a server? Can I somehow use a virtual display?
By default, I'm getting the following:

RuntimeError: error: ERROR: In vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 459: vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x62da2426f640): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=


I use pyvirtualdisplay in the manipulation repo:
    # Setup a virtual display if needed (for simulating cameras)
    if scenario.cameras and sys.platform == "linux" and os.getenv("DISPLAY") is None:
        from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

        virtual_display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
        virtual_display.start()

If necessary, you might also need to apt install xvfb.

Worked. Thanks!
